# fxFlex adding 100% width to the child components

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am using the Flex Layout Angular, which is great I have added the flex to the child component `<div fxFlex="100">` which makes the DIV to width 100%, however, the below component width is also 100%. I don't want to apply a width to the inner component. How can I prevent this ??

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-card>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <div fxFlex="100"> ==============================> added 100% width to the div, which is fine
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline"> ==================> However, inner component is also added to 100% width it should be default
                    <mat-label>Make</mat-label>
                    <mat-select>
                        <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem until I found the tool **Layout demos** [1](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) where I can play with the options.

There I learned that to prevent the child from filling the width of the parent, this directive `fxLayoutAlign =" start start "` should be used in the child element.

This option must be declared since the default value of fxLayoutAlign is `start stretch` which in css is equivalent to

```css
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: stretch;
align-content: stretch;
```

Which is equivalent to the element having max-width: 100% if flex-direction: column; else max-height: 100%

In your code the answer will be:

```html
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <mat-card>
    <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
      <div fxFlex="100">

                            <!-- Change start here  -->
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                            <!-- Change start here   -->
        
        
          <mat-label>Make</mat-label>
          <mat-select>
            <mat-option>None</mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

My first answer for stackverflow .